# Weird behavior date() php function. Bug?

Tags: php, date

I tried to add 3 and 4 days to date. Problem is date() in both cases returns same date. Why?

```
$intTime = strtotime('2012-10-25')+(3*86400);
date('Y-m-d', $intTime );

$intTime = strtotime('2012-10-25')+(4*86400);
date('Y-m-d', $intTime );
```

returns 2012-10-28

PHP 5.2.6-1

and

Timezone: Europe/Warsaw, PHP: 5.2.17

But

```
$intTime = strtotime('2012-10-25 +3 days'); 
echo date('Y-m-d', $intTime );

$intTime = strtotime('2012-10-25 +4 days'); 
echo date('Y-m-d', $intTime );
```

returns valid date.

Comment: This works for me. Returns 2012-10-28 and 2012-10-29. What dates are returned when you echo them?

Comment: +1 @Trevor, same for me too. Are you running your server on the planet Mercury or something ;)

Comment: What version of PHP are you testing with?

Comment: Works as supposed for me too. Try running it at http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and echoing it.

Comment: I think we need to see the actual code you are using to output the dates... that would help

Comment: Works fine, refer http://codepad.org/UKiFfswe

Comment: In your locale, you may have run afoul of the daylight savings time change ([which is Oct 28 in some places](http://www.webexhibits.org/daylightsaving/b2.html)). Simply adding 86400 is not reliable for adding days.

Comment: What timezone are you in, and do the clocks change this weekend?

Comment: I note that you're using PHP 5.2. I would **strongly** recommend that you upgrade to at least 5.3. For one, 5.2 has been unsupported for nearly two years now; it's way out of date and hasn't had any security patches in that time. And also, while the PHP DateTime class I recommended in my answer is available in 5.2, it was improved significantly in 5.3 (ie the date_add function isn't available in 5.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a different method for your day additions - this is simpler to understand:

```
$time = strtotime('+3 day',strtotime('2012-10-25'));
$data = date('Y-m-d', $time);
```

I'm not sure if the above would take into account daylight savings however as mentioned by  Michael Berkowski.

Comment: Yes, this returns valid date. Thanks.

Comment: no problem, good to know that it seems to take into account day length :) plus I wasn't aware you could use it like `strtotime('2012-10-25 +3 day');` - +1 good find.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a bug in PHP -- you're falling foul of daylight savings.

The date you're creating using `strtotime()` doesn't specify the time, so it defaults to midnight (ie 00:00:00).

When you add 24 hours to a timestamp, it would normally end up at the same time on the following day. However, because this weekend is the end of daylight savings in some countries, that particular day is one hour longer -- thus adding 24 hours ends up with a timestamp that maps to 23h00 on the *same day*.

This is why you're getting this odd effect.

The solutions are:

1. Have your system only work in UCT time, not local time. UCT does not have daylight savings, so won't be affected by this. If you need to input or output times in local format, convert them before doing anything else. You can set the system to UCT either in your PHP.ini file, or by using the [`date_default_timezone_set()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).
2. Use PHP's [`DateTime` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead of the old-style date functions. This class works in UCT by default, and includes a `date_add()` method which allows you to specify a number of days, bypassing this whole issue completely. (the class also has a lot of other nice functionality that is much better and easier to use than the old style functions).
   **NOTE: The `DateTime::add()` method is only available from PHP 5.3. If you're stuck on 5.2 you can't use it (but if so I also strongly recommend you upgrade, because you're badly out of date)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your timezone, the date, DST, the moon phase and whether you've seen a black cat that morning or not, both timestamps may end up on the same day, one early in the morning and the other late at night. One day is not consistently 86400 seconds long.

Use proper date/time handling functions. [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) can add time using `+3 days` syntax, [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime) can be used to create new timestamps with some involved math, but the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class is the most robust and versatile method to manipulate timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens when you're in a timezone that experiences daylight savings time during those dates. When that happens, adding `86400` is erroneous because there are now no longer 86400 seconds in a day.

Try changing your date-generation to:

```
$intTime = strtotime('2012-10-25 +3 days');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```